# Capping off an unused wire

Tags: wiring

I wanted to update a light switch,  and when i opened it up, found it was a light/fan combo switch  with no fan at the ceiling box, just a light. The image shows the old switch on the right.(left side is new switch with only ground wire attached. I want to disconnect
the 2 black wires (connected to the red and black wires of the old switch,and connect them to the new switch screws. That leaves me with the red wire (connected to the yellow on the old switch). If my connection plan is correct, can I just cap off the red wire with a wing nut and electrical tape?
[image: electricalswitch]

Comment: The old switch (on the right, does not look like a simple switch, what is it

Comment: It's a light/fan combo switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the existing wire nut and cap the red wire in the junction box. You'll want to verify that the red wire is capped in the ceiling box and that the light is fed from the black wire.

Comment: For a single wire in a wire nut, either go to a smaller size nut or add tape to ensure it doesn't come off. I've never felt that a single wire in a nut that was holding two wires was secure enough. Maybe it is, but a tug on the nut didn't seem secure to me. Otherwise +1.